# How to concatenate Jenkins parameter ${POM_VERSION} for Maven?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

So trying to create a bespoke version for a Maven build in Jenkins via the [Maven Release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) the following goals and options are specified:

```
-B  release:prepare -DdryRun=true -DreleaseVersion=${POM_VERSION}-VERSION
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error parsing version, cannot determine next version: Unable to parse the version string: "${POM_VERSION}-VERSION"
```

`${POM_VERSION}` on its own works fine, or another string such as `-DreleaseVersion=1.1.1`, there seems to be an issue with concatenating the string and parameter.

This is setup as a Maven project in Jenkins, not a Freestyle project.

Comment: I managed to get something working with -DreleaseVersion="${POM_VERSION}-VERSION" but that resolves to: 
-DreleaseVersion=0.0.3-SNAPSHOT-VERSION

Comment: Is `0.0.3-SNAPSHOT` not the current `<version>` of your POM? Why the qualifier `-VERSION`?

Answer (score 0):

`VERSION` is not an usual qualifier. See also the following from [Understanding Maven Version Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN400):

> If you do not follow Maven versioning standards in your project versioning scheme, then for version comparison, Maven interprets the entire version as a simple string. Maven and its core plug-ins use version comparison for a number of tasks, most importantly, the release process.
>
> If you use a nonstandard versioning scheme, Maven release and version plug-in goals might not yield the expected results. Because basic string comparison is performed on nonstandard versions, version comparison calculates the order of versions incorrectly in some cases.

Using `-DreleaseVersion=${POM_VERSION}` is somehow contradictory. `release:prepare` is usually meant to prepare a *new* release with a *new* version.

Comment: Yup, totally agree, but a fix for another issue.  Using Adobe Enterprise Manager, where the package manager nests release versions within snapshot versions.